# Where to store temporary data in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Ruby, I have a controller action that immediately initiates a computationally-intensive task that takes several seconds. I want the client to poll my server and get status updates.

in my controller:

```
def complex_task
  Thread.new do
    loop do
      one_part_of_the_computationally_intensive_task
      # Note how much progress we've made, in case the client asks.
      save_progress
    end
  end
  # returns to client straightaway, but task continues in background.
end

def check_status
  # Retrieve state in here.
  get_progress
end
```

Note how `check_status` needs to pull state that is stored by the separate thread.

**How do I write the `save_progress` and `get_progress` functions?** Where do I store the state? It seems like it isn't a good idea to store it in `session`, since this gets sent to the client, but where else do I store it?

(related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139659/access-session-within-rails-controller-thread), but much more general. I expect quite different answers.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [delayed_job](http://github.com/tobi/delayed_job).  You could easily extend this so that jobs can write progress into the `delayed_jobs` table, for subsequent extraction by your `check_status()` method (or you could even add `set_status()` and `check_status()` to delayed_job ...)

Note that delayed_job was originally extracted from Shopify; I'm guessing that this means it's had some solid real-world exposure.  I'd prefer to start from a base like that than roll my own, unless I had a pretty compelling reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the status in a model, and put the status_id into the session. Alternately, you could use a database session store instead of a cookie-based one, which would keep the data you put into the session at the server side at the expense of session speed.