# Access `session` within rails controller thread

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I see / change session data from within a thread within rails? See this code snippet inside my controller:

```
def controller_action
  session[:something] = 'before'   # works properly
  Thread.new do
    session[:something] = 'after'  # out of scope.  <--- how do I fix this?
  end
end
```

(related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139421/where-to-store-temporary-data-in-rails), but much more specific. I expect quite different answers.)

Comment: I wouldn't be using threads like this personally. If you have a long running process, using a scheduler or queue is the way to go.

Comment: @Toby: Yes, agreed. Don't thread if you don't have to. DelayedJob or something similar should work better here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure why session would not be in scope by reference inside a thread, but if this is true, you could try passing the current binding to the thread as an argument:

```
Thread.new(binding) do 
    thread_session = eval("session", binding)
end
```

Or something like that. I'm still not convinced that the session is by value and not by reference in the Thread. To check this I just passed some hashes into new threads on the console, and changes made to a hash inside a thread are visible outside that thread. Is there some magic that makes session behave differently?

EDIT: Wouldn't [DelayedJob](http://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) be a better way to handle a long-running process spun off from a user request?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to change session data in a background thread?

Are you using the default cookie store, because if you are I'm not sure how this would work.  If you were to switch to the memcached/database session store you might have more luck as you can access the session after the request has finished.