# Storing Rails controller callback data in session

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session, callback

The idea is:

- Perform some time consuming action in background.
- Have the results from that action be propagated back to the controller using a callback.
- Store the result in an in memory session store.
- Have the result in session be used and available from that point onward.

[image: Async Callback]

Controller receives the results in the callback:

```
# controller callback, saves result to session
# this method is executed as expected
# session id matches the one from other controller actions
def on_counter_value_calculated(context, new_value)
  @counter = new_value
  session[:counter] = @counter
end
```

However, stored session is **lost** in subsequent calls:

```
# although the same session is targeted (same id)
# the saved value is not the same
def index
  @counter = session[:counter] || 0
end
```

I've created a small Rails project that demonstrates the issue:
https://github.com/elvanja/controller_callbak_store_in_session

Any input appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked Rails code, and if I understand correctly, session in fact comes from request:

```
# actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:132
delegate :session, :to => "@_request"
```

It seems session is valid only within request cycle context and although it can be accessed, the changes are not saved, as demonstrated by the project.

Hence, this will not work. As suggested @ [Ruby on Rails Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/rubyonrails-talk) and [Ruby Rogues](http://rubyrogues.com/), the best way to deal with this is to use Sidekiq, DelayedJob, Resque or similar frameworks.

EDIT: [Access `session` within rails controller thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139659/access-session-within-rails-controller-thread) is actually the reason (background processing in the example is done in a separate thread).